# Getting Type Mismatch on one line but nearly identical line evaluates correctly

Tags: excel, type-mismatch, vba

I am getting a Type Mismatch on the "Pc" line only. Zc and Tc evaluate correctly. All values are coming from a User Form. Values are all floating point with 2 - 4 decimals. I have tried Dim Pc as Double and get same result. Any ideas why this is happening?

Portion of code that is flaky:

```
Private Sub VelocityCalc()


Zc = Zf.Value / Zb.Value
Pc = Pb.Value / (Pf.Value + Patm.Value)
Tc = (Tf.Value + 459.67) / 519.67
```

Comment: PS: I have tried this on two different machines, one running Office 2016 and the other 2010. Same results.

Comment: Someone's doing thermodynamics! :D

Answer (score 2):

If your values are strings, `Pc = Pb.Value / (Pf.Value + Patm.Value)` could be, for instance, `Pc = "123.4567" / ("4563.342" + "231.123")`.

This would evaluate to `Pc = "123.4567" / ("4563.342231.123")` (because the `+` operator can act as a concatenation operator for strings).

Because `"4563.342231.123"` can't be cast to a numeric value, it will crash when the division is attempted.

Always convert strings to numeric types before using them as numbers:

```
Zc = CDbl(Zf.Value) / CDbl(Zb.Value)
Pc = CDbl(Pb.Value) / (CDbl(Pf.Value) + CDbl(Patm.Value))
Tc = (CDbl(Tf.Value) + 459.67) / 519.67
```